# Multi-Field Text to Columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 13 columns that has data separated by a "^" sign. What I'm trying to come up with is some code that would read each column and parse out the data in between the "^" into its own column.

I can do this on a single column but performing the function I want on each column has proved tricky.

This is easy to do on a single column of data.

```
 #df = original dataset 

 #split first column based on '^' symbol -output is a list
 df2 <-strsplit(as.character(df$`Col1`),"\\^")

 #turn list into df again
 df3 <-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,df2),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

This gives me one dataframe with the text-to-columns output of 1 column.  The problem is I have 12 other columns.

```
 Original df example: 
 col1           col2              col3 
 baby^monkey    cow^pig^sheep     tree^root^grass^man

 Desired Output:
 Col1_1  Col1_2   Col2_1   Col2_2  Col2_3   Col3_1 Col3_2 Col3_3  Col3_4
 baby    monkey  cow      pig     sheep    tree   root   grass   man
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a few functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can reshape the data into a long format, separate the strings by `^` into individual rows, make row numbers along the column groups, and spread back into wide shape.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "col1           col2              col3
baby^monkey    cow^pig^sheep     tree^root^grass^man", 
                 header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = "\\^") %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  unite(key, key, row) %>%
  spread(key, value)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 9
#>   col1_1 col1_2 col2_1 col2_2 col2_3 col3_1 col3_2 col3_3 col3_4
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 baby   monkey cow    pig    sheep  tree   root   grass  man
```